# LZMA Decompress - about LZMA properties

Tags: python, algorithm, compression

I'm writing code for parsing files compressed with the LZMA algorithm.

```
import lzma
import struct
from bitio import bit_open

def main(file):
  f = bit_open(file,'r')
  magic = f.ReadString(8) # 8 Bytes
  version = f.ReadInt()   # 4 Bytes
  fileSize = f.ReadInt()  # 4 Bytes
  props = f.byte_file.read(5) # 5 Bytes
  dicSize = struct.unpack('<I', bytes(props[1:5]))[0]
  d = props[0]
  lc, d = divmod(d, 9)
  pb, lp = divmod(d, 5)
  filters=[
    {
        "id": lzma.FILTER_LZMA2,
        "dict_size": dicSize,
        "lc": lc,
        "lp": lc,
        "pb": pb
    }
  ]
  decompressor = lzma.LZMADecompressor(
      format=lzma.FORMAT_RAW,
      filters=filters
  )
  myData = f.byte_file.read()
  result = decompressor.decompress(myData)
  print(result)
```

This is my code.

I didn't get an error when I run the code, code print just

```
b''
```

I already checked variable `myData` and it contains compressed data.

Is there a problem with using the Specifying custom filter chains?
or how can I change my code to input the LZMA properties?

Comment: How was the file compressed?  Do you have an example file?  Make a [mcve].

Comment: Please state the header parts are plausible.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about high-level functions, such as `ReadString`, `ReadInt` and the comments that say it's 8 or 4 bytes. It's quite unlikely that code will work everywhere. You need to consider machine endianness, and that types `Int` can be of different sizes depending on the Python version, runtime, and the CPU it's being executed.